# Bug with "URL" in shouldInteractWith method

Tags: swift, url, uitextview

I'm trying to catch the YouTube URL in UITextView with this delegate method to open it on Youtube app:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if URL.absoluthePath.contains("youtube.com"), let youtubeURL = URL(string: "youtube://" + id) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(youtubeURL)
    }
}
```

And I have this error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'URL'

Because Xcode thinks I'm using 'URL' variable instead of using URL(string: "")! declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Foundation.URL`

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        if let youtubeURL = Foundation.URL(string: "youtube://" + id), URL.absoluteString.contains("youtube.com")  {
            UIApplication.shared.open(youtubeURL)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 issues in your code, but first of all this is a pretty bad naming by Apple. The internal parameter label should be `url` (lowercased). But as internal parameter labels are arbitrary, you can change the signature yourself to

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, 
                shouldInteractWith url: URL, 
                in characterRange: NSRange, 
                interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
```

The other issues are:

- You have to return a `Bool` value.
- There is no API `absoluthePath` in `URL`, you mean `absoluteString`

A more efficient domain check is to use the `host` parameter of the URL

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if url.host?.hasSuffix("youtube.com") == true, let youtubeURL = URL(string: "youtube://" + id) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(youtubeURL)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I learn two things with your answer:
- I didn't know I can change the signature
- I didn't know the url.host method
Thank you :)

Comment: I know for returning, I just copied only the part with error.
I know also for absoluteString, typo :)